# WPF Datagrid size stretching issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i have `mainGrid` containing `scrollviwer` containing `stackPanelContent`.

I ham adding a grid with two columns, each containing a `DataGrid`. The problem is DataGrid1 is empty and DataGrid2 contains data. But My DataGrid1 is also expanding in height with respect to DataGrid2. Why such behavior?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
var datagridDetails = new DataGrid { IsReadOnly = true, AutoGenerateColumns = false };
var columnDetails = new DataGridTextColumn
{
    Header = "Details",
    MinWidth = 400,
    Width = StackPanelContent.ActualWidth/2 - 8,
    CanUserSort = false,
    CanUserResize = false
};
datagridDetails.Columns.Add(columnDetails);

var datagridTopic = new DataGrid { IsReadOnly = true, AutoGenerateColumns = false};
var columnTopic = new DataGridTextColumn
{
    Header = "Topic",
    MinWidth = 400,
    Width = StackPanelContent.ActualWidth/2 - 8,
    CanUserSort = false,
    CanUserResize = false,
    Binding = new Binding("Title")
};
datagridTopic.Columns.Add(columnTopic);
datagridTopic.ItemsSource = topics;

var myGrid = new Grid();
var col1 = new ColumnDefinition();
var col2 = new ColumnDefinition();
myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1);
myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col2);
StackPanelContent.Children.Add(myGrid);

Grid.SetColumn(datagridDetails, 0);
myGrid.Children.Add(datagridDetails);

Grid.SetColumn(datagridTopic, 1);
myGrid.Children.Add(datagridTopic);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change [`VerticalAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.verticalalignment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `DataGrid` to be `Top` instead of `Stretch`.

---

***Why that happened?***
Keep in mind that on a vertically aligned `StackPanel` all child controls get *stretched horizontally*. On the other hand horizontally aligned `StackPanel` - *vertically stretch* child elements. `StackPanel` does this by setting the corresponding property on its child controls to `Stretch`.

[`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks that did the trick, but i still don't know why would that happen in 1st place.

Comment: i'm reading the msdn article u provided for why that happened, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Declare data grid as follow:

```
var datagridDetails = new DataGrid { IsReadOnly = true, AutoGenerateColumns = false, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top};
```